# Automate Excel data to Powerpoint (VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint containing tables that monthly must be updated with new numbers. There are approx 30 slides, and they all contain other elements than the tables, but only the tables needs update.

At the moment we have linked the files so when updated in excel, they will also update in powerpoint. However I have found this solution to be where little flexible, and also the fact that the tables actually end up as pictures in the powerpoint is annoying.
I figured that a VBA must be able to automatically fix this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This isn't a code-writing service, but we can help you spot mistakes in things you've already tried; please clarify your question a bit to include what you've tried so far. If it's just 'is this possible' then I can answer yes, it is, although quite complex.

Comment: Hi Spencer, thank you.